# How can I replace a password with another one on Chrome for all websites and subdomains that use it?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, passwords

One of my passwords is used by several subdomains of a website. It is stored in Chrome. I changed that password. How can I replace a password with another one on Chrome for all websites and subdomains that use it? I don't want to edit the password for each subdomain one by one in Chomre settings.